# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView selected item has weird gray border?

Tags: xamarin.forms, datatemplate, datatrigger

I'm coding in Visual Studio Mac, using the iPhone 8 simulator running iOS 13.6.

Here's my code for my collection view:

```
       <CollectionView
            Margin="0"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            x:Name="selectableItemsList"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            SelectionChanged="selectableItemsList_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image
                        Source="{Binding Image}"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        HeightRequest="100"
                        WidthRequest="100"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup
                                Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState
                                    Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState
                                    Name="Focused" />
                                <VisualState
                                    Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Yellow" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Image> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Here's what the items look like when not selected:

[image]

And here's what they look like when selected:

[image]

See that grey line at the top and left side of each icon? How the heck do I get rid of that?

Is there a way to do a work-around that uses a data trigger to change the image's background color when the item is selected?

**Please Note:**

Moving the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` section into a style in a `ResourceDictionary` does *not* solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to check it yet, but IIRC I did try that before posting here. Once I confirm, I'll add a comment and/or accept your answer.

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works:).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with put the image inside a Grid:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image 
                Source="{Binding .}"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HeightRequest="100"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Start">
               
            </Image>

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup
                        Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState
                            Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState
                            Name="Focused" />
                    <VisualState
                            Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter
                                    Property="BackgroundColor"
                                    Value="Yellow" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Well, I did not see those lines when I test on my side. You can also have a try with [offical sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/), there is no  gray border too.